# prolog, changing atoms in expression

Tags: list, prolog

my task is to write a predicate `subst(T,A,V,R)` that changes all occurences of atom `A` in expression `T` to atom `V` and the result is presented as `R`.

For instance:

```
subst(object(one, two),one,three,R). //R=object(three,two).
susbt(a+1,a,2,R). //R=2+1.
```

It could be easy with the approach: I change the expression to list using `T=..L`, then I compare every element of `L` with `A` and if they're the same, I can change it to `V`. In the end, I can reverse the very first action (to get the expression again), but I don't know how to deal with situation like:
`subst((a+1)*(b+3),a,2,W)`. // ?

Starting with something like `T=..L` I can get `[*,a+1,b+3]`, but now if I would like to change `a` to `2`, I can't check every consecutive item of `L` because some of them are not simple atoms/numbers. Now my question is, is there any built-in predicate to check if the element in a list is like: `a`, `1`, etc., but not `a+1`? I mean if I wouldn't like to check first if it's atom or not and later if it's number of not.

Or maybe there is some easier approach to that matter?

**EDIT1:**
Thanks for comments. I have so far:

```
subst(T,A,V,R):-T=..L,make_simple(L,L1),replace(L1,A,V,L2),to_exp(L2,R).

make_simple([],[]).
make_simple([H|T],[H|W]):-atom(H),make_simple(T,W),!.
make_simple([H|T],[H|W]):-number(H),make_simple(T,W),!.
make_simple([H|T],[W1|W2]):- \+atom(H),\+number(H),H=..H1,make_simple(H1,W1),make_simple(T,W2).

replace([],_,_,[]).
replace([A|T],A,V,[V|W]):- replace(T,A,V,W),!.
replace([H|T],A,V,[H|W]):- H\=A,\+is_list(H),replace(T,A,V,W),!.
replace([H|T],A,V,[W1|W2]):-H\=A, is_list(H),replace(H,A,V,W1),replace(T,A,V,W2),!.

to_exp([],[]).
to_exp([H|T],[H|W]):- \+is_list(H),to_exp(T,W),!.
to_exp([H|T],[W1|W2]):- is_list(H), (what next?)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to put ap those pieces together now in `to_exp` part. Especially, when it's like:

```
to_exp([*,[+,a,1],[-,3,b]]).
```

or even worse:

```
to_exp([*,[+,[*,4,2],1],[-,3,b]]).
```

What I mean, if an element of an outer list is a list, I don't know how to identify that it's exactly list of three elements, where each of them is an atom/number. Any tips?:)

**EDIT2**

Okay, I was told that it's getting far too complicated. Maybe, but I'm new in Prolog and I'm using only tools/techniques that I've learned so far, because the tasks I am supposed to do are constructed this way. Of course, there must be simpler ways, like that one suggested by @mat, yet I haven't learned about `dif` or `maplist` predicates so far. This is why I've decided to continue this one this way.

I've found out that there is no need to check for `atom` and `number` separately. There's `atomic/1` that returns true if a term is number, atom, or en empty list (so the problem mentioned by @mat about SWI-Prolog doesn't seem to matter that much). Following that, I've changed previous predicates and I've finished `to_exp` as:

```
subst(T,A,V,R):-T=..L,make_simple(L,L1),replace(L1,A,V,L2),to_exp(L2,R).

make_simple([],[]).
make_simple([H|T],[H|W]):-atomic(H),make_simple(T,W),!.
make_simple([H|T],[W1|W2]):- \+atomic(H),H=..H1,make_simple(H1,W1),make_simple(T,W2),!.

replace([],_,_,[]).
replace([A|T],A,V,[V|W]):- replace(T,A,V,W),!.
replace([H|T],A,V,[H|W]):- H\=A,\+is_list(H),replace(T,A,V,W),!.
replace([H|T],A,V,[W1|W2]):-H\=A, is_list(H),replace(H,A,V,W1),replace(T,A,V,W2),!.

to_exp([],[]).
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):-atomic(H1),atomic(H2),L=..[Z,H1,H2],!.
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):- \+atomic(H1),atomic(H2),to_exp(H1,W1),L=..[Z,W1,H2].
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):- atomic(H1),\+atomic(H2),to_exp(H2,W1),L=..[Z,H1,W1].
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):- \+atomic(H1),\+atomic(H2),to_exp(H1,W1),to_exp(H2,W2),L=..[Z,W1,W2].
```

Now, it works both for functors and arguments, simple and nested ones.
Anyway, thanks for the influence, I definitely will consider using `dif` and `maplist` in the future. Cheers:)

Comment: You are on the right track. You can use `atom/1`: True if its argument is an atom. Beware: It's a non-monotonic predicate, so use it only when the argument is sufficiently instantiated. See for example `?- atom(X), X = a.` vs. `?- X = a, atom(X).`.

Comment: Why not recursively break it down using `=..`? So `(a+1)*(b+3)` leads to `[*,a+1,b+3]` and each of those elements leads to `[*]`, `[+,a,1]`, and `[+,b,3]`. At the lowest level, you can find your atoms to replace. You can use mat's idea of using `atom` to know when you've "hit bottom". `number(X)` is true if `X` is a number.

Comment: How would you want `subst(foo(a, b), foo, bar, R).` to work? Should it fail? Should it succeeds with `R = foo(a, b)`? Or should it succeed with `R = bar(a, b)`?

Comment: =.. applies to expressions also, since expressions are just terms: `?- 1+2 =.. [+,1,2].`

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I've edited my question, can you look at it?:)

Comment: You are making this far too complicated. Please take into account the completely uniform inductive definition of terms and proceed by handling the cases uniformly. For example, there is absolutely no need to handle *lists* specially.

Comment: @mat I understand your point, but can you provide some example? And what you mean by 'far too complicated'? Last part, or the whole process of solving this task?

Comment: @mat I just don't know how I could finish that not handling the lists..

Comment: A list is also just a term, you can handle the cases uniformly. SWI-Prolog has made the extremely unfortunate decision to let `[]` *not* denote an atom, but in ISO-Prolog, `[]` is an atom. Try SWI-Prolog with the `--traditional` flag (which I recommend in any case) to see what I mean.

Comment: @mat I still don't get how it might help me. The thing is I don't know how to handle those cases- all I can see is an atom, number or a list (there's never empty list so I don't know what's your idea about?). Please, show me some example..

Comment: All I see are terms, and what you need to express is how to replace a subterm by another term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough, there's more efficient answer to this question I will post this one for those, who are begginners in Prolog like me, cause it's using very basic operations:

```
subst(T,A,V,R):-T=..L,make_simple(L,L1),replace(L1,A,V,L2),to_exp(L2,R).

make_simple([],[]).
make_simple([H|T],[H|W]):-atomic(H),make_simple(T,W),!.
make_simple([H|T],[W1|W2]):- \+atomic(H),H=..H1,make_simple(H1,W1),make_simple(T,W2),!.

replace([],_,_,[]).
replace([A|T],A,V,[V|W]):- replace(T,A,V,W),!.
replace([H|T],A,V,[H|W]):- H\=A,\+is_list(H),replace(T,A,V,W),!.
replace([H|T],A,V,[W1|W2]):-H\=A, is_list(H),replace(H,A,V,W1),replace(T,A,V,W2),!.

to_exp([],[]).
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):-atomic(H1),atomic(H2),L=..[Z,H1,H2],!.
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):- \+atomic(H1),atomic(H2),to_exp(H1,W1),L=..[Z,W1,H2].
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):- atomic(H1),\+atomic(H2),to_exp(H2,W1),L=..[Z,H1,W1].
to_exp([Z,H1,H2],L):- \+atomic(H1),\+atomic(H2),to_exp(H1,W1),to_exp(H2,W2),L=..[Z,W1,W2].
```

Comment: Beginners in Prolog like you should rather treat this as an example how *not* to solve this task. Instead, please take into account the completely regular structure of Prolog terms, and make this more general. For example, what about the following query: `?- subst(f(a,b,c), a, 2, R).`. It incorrectly **fails** with your code. It works with my solution. Recall that there are also Prolog terms that do not have arity 2. Another example: `?- subst(f(a), a, 2, R).` It **fails** with your code. It works with the solution I posted.

Answer (score 3):

Please take into account the complete regularity of Prolog terms.

```
substitution(A0, A0, A, A).    
substitution(T0, A0, A, T) :-
        dif(T0, A0),
        T0 =.. [F|Args0],
        maplist(subst_(A0, A), Args0, Args),
        T =.. [F|Args].

subst_(A0, A, T0, T) :- substitution(T0, A0, A, T).
```

Example query and its result:

```
?- substitution(a+b+[c,d,a], a, 2, R).
R = 2+b+[c, d, 2] ;
false.
```